# EF Core Deleting Entities in Disconnected Environment

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm having real difficulty with EF Core with a Web API project I'm working... to me EF Core is not intuitive at all.  I'm in a disconnected environment and I'm trying to update Sudoku games.  EF Core is spending more time deleting connections between users and their apps and roles than in updating the game.  How do I disable delete statements in an update?  There is no reason for deletes, I don't need them.  How do I stop them?

The method is as follows, the game is loaded as a graph and my understanding is this code should change everything tracked to modified or added.  To me it seems like EF Core is going out of it's way to delete things... this makes no sense.  I never instructed it to delete anything:

```
    async public Task<IRepositoryResponse> Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        var result = new RepositoryResponse();

        try
        {
            dbSet.Update(entity);

            context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(entity,
                e => {

                    var dbEntry = (IEntityBase)e.Entry.Entity;

                    if (dbEntry.Id != 0)
                    {
                        e.Entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
                    }
                });

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            result.Success = true;
            result.Object = entity;

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            result.Success = false;
            result.Exception = exp;

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a work around but it is the equivalent to the fixing your bike with bubblegum and tape.  It's ugly... but it works.  Before I save the game I create a list of all associated apps and roles and then recreate and resave the values after **await context.SaveChangesAsync();**.  The code is listed below:

```
        async public Task<IRepositoryResponse> Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            var result = new RepositoryResponse();

            try
            {
                entity.DateUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;

                context.Games.Update(entity);

                context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(entity,
                    e => {

                        var dbEntry = (IEntityBase)e.Entry.Entity;

                        if (dbEntry.Id != 0)
                        {
                            e.Entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            e.Entry.State = EntityState.Added;
                        }
                    });

                var apps = new List<App>();
                var roles = new List<Role>();

                foreach (var userApp in entity.User.Apps)
                {
                    apps.Add(userApp.App);
                }

                foreach (var userRole in entity.User.Roles)
                {
                    roles.Add(userRole.Role);
                }

                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                foreach (var app in apps)
                {
                    userAppDbSet.Add(new UserApp(entity.UserId, app.Id));
                }

                foreach (var role in roles)
                {
                    userRoleDbSet.Add(new UserRole(entity.UserId, role.Id));
                }

                await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                result.Success = true;
                result.Object = entity;

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                result.Success = false;
                result.Exception = exp;

                return result;
            }
        }
```

There has to be a better way of doing this?  The full app can be found here, can someone tell me a better way of setting this up:

https://github.com/Joseph-Anthony-King/SudokuCollective